# compare vector lists

Tags: python, vector, blender

### I need to **compare** two list of vectors and take their **equal elements**, like:

```
veclist1 = [(0.453 , 0.232 , 0.870), (0.757 , 0.345 , 0.212), (0.989 , 0.232 , 0.543)]
veclist2 = [(0.464 , 0.578 , 0.870), (0.327 , 0.335 , 0.562), (0.757 , 0.345 , 0.212)]

equalelements = [(0.757 , 0.345 , 0.212)]
```

---

## obs: The **order** of the elements **don't matter**!

And also, *if possible* I wanted to only consider till the **2nd decimal** in the comparison
but without rounding or shortening them. Is it possible ?
Thx in advance!

Comment: Which vector should be in the result if 2 vectors are considered equal, but are not the same? e.g. `(0.000, 0.200, 0.500)` and `(0.001, 0.199, 0.502)`.

Comment: My problems is that I have to consider "equal" vectors with a certain amount of respite, but, in the end they should be exactly as they were before, because they describe an exact position in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Get new lists with rounded values
veclist1_rounded = [tuple(round(val, 2) for val in vec) for vec in veclist1]
veclist2_rounded = [tuple(round(val, 2) for val in vec) for vec in veclist2]

# Convert to sets and calculate intersection (&)
slct_rounded = set(veclist1_rounded) & set(veclist2_rounded)

# Pick original elements from veclist1:
#   - get index of the element from the rounded list
#   - get original element from the original list
equalelements = [veclist1[veclist1_rounded.index(el)] for el in slct_rounded]
```

In this case we select the entries of `veclist1` if only the rounded entries are equal. Otherwise the last line needs to be adjusted.

If all original elements are needed, the final list can be calculated using both original lists:

```py
equalelements = ([veclist1[veclist1_rounded.index(el)] for el in slct_rounded]
                 + [veclist2[veclist2_rounded.index(el)] for el in slct_rounded])
```

**Note:** `round` might have [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points), which should be [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points/35117668#35117668) in current Python version. Nevertheless, it might be better to use strings instead:

```py
get_rounded = lambda veclist: [tuple(f'{val:.2f}' for val in vec) for vec in veclist]
veclist1_rounded, veclist2_rounded = get_rounded(veclist1), get_rounded(veclist2)
```

Comment: I see! So that 1st code should convert the vectors back after the operation is done? (sorry, I'm bad at coding),

Comment: do you need *all* coordinates if only the rounded coordinates match? (and the original coordinates are slightly different)

Comment: not totally sure, only testing. Because the object will still be at same place, what I need is it's coordinates to apply texture upon it. I'm trying to develop a cel-shading art style based on a lecture of people from Dragon Ball Fighterz.